# Class scope issue

Tags: javascript, class, scope

How do I make my objects property available within the callback?

```js
//entrypoint.js
var DeviceManager = require('./class')
DM = new DeviceManager()

DM.start();

var t = setInterval(function() {
  console.log("Module.isLoaded = " + DM.isLoaded);
}, 500);
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log("Stopping");
  clearInterval(t);
  DM.stop();
}, 10000);


//class.js
module.exports = class DeviceManager {
    constructor(){
        this.isLoaded = false;
        this._timer= null;
    }

    start(){

        console.log('starting timer')
        this._timer = setInterval( function() {
            console.log('timer callback')
            this.isLoaded = !this.isLoaded;
        },1000)

    }

    stop() {
        console.log('stopping timer')
        clearInterval(this._timer)
    }
}
```

Basically this line doesnt work, because it doesnt have access to the correct *this* I assume.

```
this.isLoaded = !this.isLoaded
```

Also, since im all around pretty new at this, any feedback/corrections are very welcome.

Comment: Actually, `this` in that context doesn't refer to the class.

Comment: @Philter that's the wrong duplicate. It's not about the Prototype

Answer (score -1):

Try using an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) for your `setInterval` while it's in the class.

> An arrow function expression has a shorter syntax than a function expression and does not have its own `this`

```
start() {
    this._timer = setInterval( () => {
        this.isLoaded = !this.isLoaded;
    }, 1000)
}
```